# How to append to a file with fstream fstream::app flag seems not to work

Tags: c++, fstream

i simply want to write (append) to a logfile. I looked it up here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/open/

so this is  what  i did

```
#include <fstream>

fstream outfile;

//outfile.open("/tmp/debug.txt" );  // works, simply for writing
outfile.open("/tmp/debug.txt", fstream::app );  // does nothing

outfile << "START" << endl;

outfile.close();
```

Comment: You can also use ofstream, your code would work with that.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`fstream::app|fstream::out` instead of `fstream::app`. `app` doesn't make sense without specifying `out` (one could think it should have implied `out`, but it doesn't).

Comment: fstream will provide defaults if you don't supply an argument, but if you do supply one (like app) it won't automatically OR yours with the default ones.

Comment: `fstream::app` doesn't necessarily mean output append, but `ofstream::app` means output append (because of `ofstream`). In other words, it's the stream type not the opening mode.