# How to append file in c++ using fstream?

Tags: c++, fstream

I try to append file in C++. At start file doesn't exists. After operations there is only one line in file instead of five (5 calls of this method). It looks like file is creating, next every write operation file is cleaned out and new string is added.

```
void storeUIDL(char *uidl) {
        fstream uidlFile(uidlFilename, fstream::app | fstream::ate);

        if (uidlFile.is_open()) {
        uidlFile << uidl;
        uidlFile.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Cannot open file";
    }
}
```

I tried with `fstream::in ,fstream::out`. How to append string correctly in this file?

Thank you in advance.

edit:

Here is wider point of view:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    MailInfo info = mails[i];
    cout << "Downloading UIDL for email " << info.index << endl;

    char *uidl = new char[100];
    memset(uidl, 0, 100);
    uidl = servicePOP3.UIDL(info.index);
    if (uidl != NULL) {
        if (existsUIDL(uidl) == false) {
            cout << "Downloading mail with index " << info.index << endl;
            char *content = servicePOP3.RETR(info);

            /// save mail to file
            string filename = string("mail_" + string(uidl) + ".eml");
            saveBufferToFile(content, filename.c_str());
            storeUIDL(uidl);
            sleep(1);
        } else {
            cout << "Mail already exists." << endl;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "UIDL for email " << info.index << " does not exists";
    }

    memset(uidl, 0, 100);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Try to remove `fstream::ate`.

Comment: Try this: `fstream uidlFile;
uidlFile.open(uidlFilename, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);`

Comment: still only last line is stored in this file.

Comment: Yes. It is weird but not working... please have a look on edited question. Added code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works.. `std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app` .

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

    char filename[ ] = "Text1.txt";

     fstream uidlFile(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);


      if (uidlFile.is_open()) 
      {
        uidlFile << filename<<"\n---\n";
        uidlFile.close();
      } 
      else 
      {
        cout << "Cannot open file";
      }




   return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I try to call this in loop there is only line with "Text1.txt" and the second line with "---". The same case as mine. I can't add more than one line in a loop. Only last is added.

Comment: OK, this does the job.  fstream uidlFile(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question has been answered [over yonder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712415/3624257).

Give this a shot:

```
fstream uidFile(uidFilename, fstream::out | fstream:: app | fstream::ate);
```

**Edit:**

I wrote this code and compiled it in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 x64.  It works perfectly for me.  It looks like the other answer worked for you, but please let me know if this does as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void save(char * string)
{
    fstream myFile("test.txt", fstream::out | fstream::app);

    if(myFile.is_open())
    {
        myFile.write(string, 100);
        myFile << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error writing to file";
    }
}

int main()
{
    char string[100] = {};



    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            string[j] = i + 48; //48 is the ASCII value for zero
        }

        save(string);
    }

    cin >> string[0]; //Pause

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed. I added more code in first post.

Comment: Does your file contain all 5 strings on one line or just the 5th string on one line?

Comment: Actually after this for loop file contains only one line which has been added as the last one. There should be five lines of texts.

Comment: Ok, just a wild guess... try adding `uidFile.flush()`         Also, try removing `fstream::ate`

Comment: No changes after using `flush` and removing `ate`.

Comment: If you don't have this answered by the time I get home I will try coding it and post working code. I'm sorry I couldn't help now. On a side note, what is your system?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using OS X 10.9 and this is a Consol Application.